# Convert Datetime to string in GMT format?

Tags: apex, soql, datetime, salesforce-id

```
String formatedDt = dt.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');
```

I want to used this string in dyamic SOQL but it gives me formatted string in localtimezone, can anyone help me how do i get it in GTM ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use DateTime's formatGMT to format the time according to your specs in GMT.

```
String formatedDt = dt.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');
```

Comment: You are a star man !

Comment: @sfdxfox your answers from the past are still helpful :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use the dateGMT() method:

> dateGMT()
>
> Return the Date component of a Datetime in the GMT time zone.
>   Signature
>
> public Date dateGMT()
>
> Return Value
>
> Type: Date

Example:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(2006, 3, 16, 23, 0, 0);
Date myDate = myDateTime.dateGMT();
Date expected = Date.newInstance(2006, 3, 17);
System.assertEquals(expected, myDate);
```

from the [Apex developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_dateGMT)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.but i need at a string to used as dynamic soql.

Comment: see @sfdcfox's answer above - formatGMT method instead of dateGMT() for formatting existing dateTime