# How to convert datetime in GMT when input format contains AM/PM?

Tags: apex, datetime

From UI I am getting this input:

Date : `2020-09-25`
Time : `12:15 AM`

Now when I try to save this to DB it saves as `2020-09-24T17:15:00.000Z`

And when it gets shown in UI again after refresh the time changes to `12:15 PM`

The logic is summarized below, try to run this, the final result changes to PM:

```
String strFormattedCorpTime = '12:15 AM'.split(' ')[0] + ':00' + '12:15 AM'.split(' ')[1];

System.debug(strFormattedCorpTime);
System.debug(Datetime.valueOf('2020-09-25'+' '+strFormattedCorpTime).format('yyyy/dd/MM hh:mm a'));
```

I would like to save 12:15 AM in GMT format, so that while showing on UI it shows whatever user has saved datetime with. How can I do that?

Comment: This https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/186802 incombination with https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/235807 helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String datetimeParseFormatGMT = Datetime.parse('09/25/2020' + ' ' + '12:15 AM').formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');
Datetime dtNew = (Datetime) JSON.deserialize('"'+datetimeParseFormatGMT+'"', Datetime.class);

System.debug(dtNew);
```

`JSON.serialize` was the key to convert datetime as string to datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:
*System.debug(Datetime.valueOf('2020-09-25'+' '+strFormattedCorpTime).format('yyyy/dd/MM hh:mm a'));*

The valueOf function is not considering AM or PM while converting the string to datetime. Hence the output of the valueOf function when formatted using *'yyyy/dd/MM hh:mm a'* gives an incorrect value.

**Solution**:
If a correct 24 hour format is passed to the code mentioned above, it converts correctly.
System.debug(Datetime.valueOf('2020-09-25'+' '+'00:15:00').format('yyyy/dd/MM hh:mm a'));
-> 2020/25/09 12:15 AM

I could not find an out of the box function to do the conversion from 12 hour to 24 hour format. Hence created a method in anonymous window.

```
public static String formatTime(String t) {
    string a = t.split(' ')[1];
    String hours = t.substringBefore(':');

    if (a == 'AM' && hours == '12')
        t = '00:' + t.substringAfter(':');
    else if (a == 'PM' && hours != '12')
        t = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(hours) + 12) + ':' + t.substringAfter(':');

    return t.split(' ')[0]+':00'
 }
```

Comment: But shouldn't  `a` in `'yyyy/dd/MM hh:mm a' ` consider AM or PM

Comment: Yes it does.
In the solution section, you can see for datetime '2020-09-25 00:15:00' it gave 2020/25/09 12:15 AM.
In your scenario, datetime passed from valueOf function is '2020-09-25 12:15:00' hence a in 'yyyy/dd/MM hh:mm a' converted it to 2020/25/09 12:15 PM.
The valueOf function does not handle AM/PM passed from strFormattedCorpTime.